# How to convert my Apache .htaccess rewrite rules to lighttpd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lighttpd

i'm looking to convert this .htaccess file to lighttpd rewrite rule, could somebody help me out with this one?

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at the lighttpd tutorial for Migrating from Apache. As far as I know there's no direct mapping from Apache for rewrites.

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/MigratingFromApache